# Laravel select the last row of linked table using eloquent relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get last row of reference table using laravel eloquent. 
I have a `User` model which has a reference to `MessageParticipant` model (returns all the message subjects the user participating in)

```
public function messages()
{
 return $this->hasMany(MessageParticipant::class);
}
```

The `MessageParticipant`refers to a `MessageSubject` model (returns the message subject participants belong to)

```
public function message_subject()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(MessageSubject::class);
}
```

The `MessageSubject`model refers to a `Message` model (return all the messages within message subject)

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
}
```

I want to get the last message of each message subject the user has participated in using a eloquent query. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `whereHas` with the `latest` method:

```
User::whereHas('message_subject', function ($query) {
    $query->with('messages' => function ($q) {
        $q->latest()->limit(1);
    });
})->get();
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)